# ng-repeat parameter in search, SpringBoot/AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here is my Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, Long>{

@Query("SELECT d FROM Data d WHERE "
+ "(:name IS NULL OR d.name like :name) AND "
+ "(:minPriority IS NULL OR d.priority >= :minPriority) AND "
+ "(:maxPriority IS NULL OR d.priority <= :maxPriority) AND "
+ "( //needed code here )"                 
Page<Data> search(
@Param("name") String name, 
@Param("minPriority") Integer minPriority, 
@Param("maxPriority") Integer maxPriority,
@Param("nameOfEmployee") String name, int page);

}
```

I have problem with namrOfEmployee parameter. In my Angular I need to   select one of values from ng-repeat:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="employee">Employees</label> 
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="newEmployee.idEmployee"    
    id="employee">
    <option ng-selected="newEmployee.idEmployee == e.id" ng-repeat="e in   
    employees" value="{{ e.id }}"> {{ e.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Employee is different entity. Do I maybe need to join Data and Employee tables? Any ideas?

Here are Data and Employee classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Data")
public class Data { 
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
@Column(name="description")
private String description;
@Column(name="priority")
private int priority;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;
@Column(name="firstName")
private String firstName;
@Column(name="lastName")
private String lastName;
@Column(name="position")
private String position;
}
```

Comment: What does your Data class look like? And your Employee class?

Comment: I added classes @Brian

Comment: @makaveli not entirely clear what the issue is still are you just trying to have a default selected value with the `<select>` tag

Comment: i just want to get e.name (employee name) from <select>, but don`t know how to do it in @Query like + "(:name IS NULL OR d.name like :name) AND "

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling a bit to understand your question here. There seem to be a few components. Primarily, your `Employee` and `Data` entities are not related from a code perspective. There is also a bit of design confusion. I've put together what seems to make sense from what you have here.

The below solution will provide this workflow:

> UI -> Request & List Employees -> Select Employee -> Request & Display associated data.

From the AngularJS side, I would first make a request for your list of employees. If you don't have that implemented yet, it's just going to be another repository (ie. `EmployeeRepository`), and an exposed endpoint for listing them. At that point, you'll have an array of employees in your UI. Once one is selected, you would then pass the request to this search method, providing the supplied parameters. In return, you would get back the datum that is associated to that employee.

First, we need to update your `@Entity` models to have a relationship:

Here, we make use of [@OneToMany](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) and [@ManyToOne](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html). `@OneToMany` means that an `Employee` has many `Data`. `@ManyToOne` means that many datum have one `Employee`.

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "position")
    private String position;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Data> data;

    // Getters/Setters/Etc

}
```

**Data.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Data")
public class Data {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "priority")
    private int priority;

    @ManyToOne
    private Employee employee;

    // Getters/Setters/Etc

}
```

Now that they are related from a JPA perspective, we can update the query:

> I noticed that you had defined `int page`. I've updated to use [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html).
>   I have also changed your parameter to employeeId, as it would appear that your > goal is to pull back data given the employee's ID.

**DataRepository.java**

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM Data d "
        + "WHERE d.employee.id = :employeeId AND "
        + "(:name IS NULL OR d.name like :name) AND "
        + "(:minPriority IS NULL OR d.priority >= :minPriority) AND "
        + "(:maxPriority IS NULL OR d.priority <= :maxPriority) ")
Page<Data> search(@Param("name") String name,
                    @Param("minPriority") Integer minPriority, 
                    @Param("maxPriority") Integer maxPriority,
                    @Param("employeeId") Long employeeId,
                    Pageable pageable);
```